# Not connecting BLE

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working with CoreBluetooth framework. So i have some doubts Could you guys please clarify.

1- I have scenario which i need to discuss, i am working with bluetooth bulbs .

I scan for the bulbs and I stopped scanning after 5 seconds just thinking that iPhone will scan all the devices in 5 seconds . Let me know how to decide the time when to stop scanning .

So after scanning i connect all the bulbs and i save all the bulb data in core data and show it on tableview . Everything works well .

Then I kill the app and turned off one bulb . Now i launch the app so iPhone scans all the bulbs gets connected except the one which is not turned on . All goes well till now .

But now i turned on the bulb which is turned off but iPhone app doesn't detect that bulbs . Which delegate will be called when this bulb is turned on .

So how to tackle this scenario.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you attempting to connect to the bulb that is turned off?  If you have a pending connection then you will get a call to `didConnect` if not then you will need to be scanning and you will get a call to `didDiscoverPeripheral`

Comment: My friend how iPhone app will notify me if bulb is powered on ? I don't want to scan continuously .

Comment: You can call `retrievePeripheralwithIdentifier` passing the identifier you have stored and the call connect if a peripheral is retrieved. Once the device is seen the connection will be completed and the connection delegate method called

Comment: Ok Thanks i will do it in this way .

Comment: Do i need to call retrievePeripheralwithIdentifier after scanning ?

Comment: Yes. You scan and then you can store the identifier. Later you can retrieve the peripheral by identified without scanning, but this method may return nil. If it does you have to scan. Really you should continue to scan while ever your app is running so that you can discover new peripherals